# Timeout a Pyspark Function Code in AWS Glue Notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have written a PySpark Function in AWS Glue Notebook, and I am trying to inquire about a way to exit out of that PySpark Function after a certain number of minutes.

I have tried to use the '*stopit*' and '*signal*' Python libraries and simple computation code will work with these libraries but when I tried to use the context_manager from '*stopit*' library with my PySpark function code, it is not getting timed out as expected. Any help will be greatly appreciated for this! Thank you!